# What are the drawbacks of @RequestBody in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

That's a silly question but I had this question during the interview of a some company.
I had a stateless backend using **Java Spring** and expected the full DTO from the request as a **@RequestBody** but they asked me what are the drawbacks of expecting a full DTO as **@RequestBody** and I couldn't answer it.

If my application is stateless, how should I expect the model from the controller?
Or is stateless backend not a good idea if you expect the whole model to use it in the service-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With DTO you usually send more data that is actually needed by remote server (although one of the main point of DTO is to reduce the number of remote calls by sending more data)
2. It maybe not straightforward to transfer DTOs to domain objects, if DTOs were complex
3. Serialization/de-serialization also could be a burden[for example binary or text]. but if you control both client and server it is not a big deal.
4. With big DTOs it become harder to keep clients and servers synchronized of changes

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please explain more about number 3? I didn't understand what you meant by controlling both client and server. Thanks again!

Comment: @AbduMuhammadal suppose you provide service to different clients and some clients are third party entities and each wants to use different serialization like protobuf and json. you have to provide the required logic to transfer those to domain objects